# batch - if folders contains the specific sub folder move it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Problem: It's only moves one folder
"FolderB.tag" to "GoodFolder"

Question: How to make It moves all folders to another by following the rules

myscript.bat

```
@echo off
md GoodFolder
md BadFolder
for /d %%i in (*.tag) do set check=%%i
if exist "%check%\SubFolderA" (move "%check%" "GoodFolder")
if not exist "%check%\SubFolderA" (move "%check%" "BadFolder")
pause
exit /b
```

mydirectory

```
BadFolder
GoodFolder
+---Folder C.tag
|   +---SubFolderA
|   \---SubFolderB

+---FolderA.tag
|   \---SubFolderB

+---FolderB.tag
|   \---SubFolderA
```

Comment: `for /d %%i in (*.tag) do set check=%%i` will set a value to a variable named `check` for each match, which means at the end of that command `%check%` will have a value containing the last directory it found. Your `if exist` commands will only therefore be working with that single directory!

Comment: Please example...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow-on from my comment, what you needed to do was to include your `if` commands within the `do` portion of the for loop.

Example as requested:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
MD GoodFolder 2>NUL
MD BadFolder 2>NUL
For /D %%I In (*.tag) Do (
    If Exist "%%I\SubFolderA\" (
        Move "%%I" "GoodFolder"
    ) Else Move "%%I" "BadFolder"
)
Pause
Exit /B
```

You'll note that I did not include the setting of a variable unnecessarily. Had you needed to do that, for some other purpose, then you'd need to have delayed the expansion of that variable in order to effectively use it.

Example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
MD GoodFolder 2>NUL
MD BadFolder 2>NUL
For /D %%I In (*.tag) Do (
    Set "check=%%I"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Exist "!check!\SubFolderA\" (
        Move "!check!" "GoodFolder"
    ) Else Move "!check!" "BadFolder"
    EndLocal
)
Pause
Exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

EnableDelayedExpansion does solve your problem but I typically like calling subroutines when dealing with for loops.  Both solutions should solve your issue.

```
@Echo Off
MD GoodFolder 2>NUL
MD BadFolder 2>NUL
For /D %%I In (*.tag) Do Call :Sorting "%%I"
Pause
Exit /B

:Sorting
If Exist "%~1\SubFolderA\" (
     Echo moving %1 to GoodFolder
     Move "%*" "GoodFolder"
) Else (
     Echo moving %1 to BadFolder
     Move "%~1" "BadFolder"
)
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: Whilst I agree that it is an alternative option, I would expect that `call`ing a subroutine may add additional overhead. Also delayed expansion wasn't necessary at all, my requested example, not the footnote code, doesn't use it. The delayed expansion code was only included to prevent comments informing the OP to add a couple of parentheses. There are a few issues with the code you have posted too. `Folder C.tag` has a space, and your file structure is incorrect, especially when the purpose of your code was to champion that structure.

Comment: WOW great catch, you are completely right and your solution is optimal.  I just like pointing out calling a subroutine can solve some problems so other users might have that options when they search for solutions to their problems.  I changed %1 to %* I think that will work.  would %~f1 or %~s1 work better?   Sorry I don't do much in CMD these days, did most of my CMD work before there were spaces in files an directories.

Comment: `%*` would have been a reasonable fix, although it is no longer necessary now that you've doublequoted the subroutine argument from `Call`. I would therefore suggest that you change it back to `Move "%~1"…`. The other suggestion I'd make is to move the bottom two lines up above the subroutine, to prevent it running once more upon normal completion. I've taken the liberty of making those changes for you, I hope you don't mind.